# Combination of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose there are two kinds of stock, and that each of them currently sells for same price in the market. The return on the one share of the first stock is a random variable with E(X)= π and Var(X) = s^2. The return on one share of the second stock also has E(Y) = π and Var(Y) = s^2. Consider the following investment plans: Plan 1: Buy 10 shares of the first stock. Plan 2: Buy 5 shares of each stock.

Compute the average return for each of the two plans and compare.

My approach: I know how to do the algebra with random variables and for both plan I'm getting average = π. As all shares have same mean, so when we averaged them, we will get average as π. Therefore, both plans will have same average return.

Can anyone plz confirm, if my way is correct or not.

Comment: Yeah it is correct.

Comment: Presumably you were intended to address the volatility as well which, of course, you really can't since no information regarding correlation is provided.

Comment: The variance at plan 1 is $100Var(X)=100s^2$, while the variance of plan 2 is $50Var(X)+50cov(X,Y)=50s^2+50cov(X,Y)$. If X does not fully depend on Y then the risk at plan 2 is smaller than at plan 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice depends on the investment plan variance. If you buy 1 share of 10 different stocks (independent) with same perfomance and risk, the total risk is obviouly very lower compared to the investment risk of buying 10 shares of one single stock...one share can gain another can loss and the risk decreases...

Formally the variance passes from $10^2$ to $10$ times

$$\mathbb{V}[10X_1]=10^2\mathbb{V}[X_1]$$

$$\mathbb{V}[X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{10}]=10\mathbb{V}[X_1]$$